# How to zoom in a mobile web using Appium

Tags: appium, mobile-website

I have scenario in my project where I need to perform zoom in action Android Mobile web using Appium automation. I have used the following method.

```
try {
        Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
        int x0 = (int) (size.getWidth()*0.5);
        int y0 = (int) (size.getHeight()*0.5);
        System.out.println(x0+" "+y0);
        driver.zoom(100, 500);
        reportStep("The Application is zoomed.", "PASS");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        reportStep("The Application could not be zoomed.", "FAIL");
    }
```

But this method working fine in Mobile apps and not working in Mobile web.
Are there any specific method or alternate work around to handle the Mobile web zoom?

I am using Appium Java-client version 5.0.4 and Selenium version 3.6.0.

Zoom and Pinch methods are not available in the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

There are not many examples out there without `zoom` method, but using [`MultiTouchAction`](https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/MultiTouchAction.html) class in conjunction with [`TouchAction`](https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/TouchAction.html) class should work as shown [here](https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/541). Note that using `moveTo` with `WebElement` and offset x,y coordinates instead of absolute is advised in that thread.

```
    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL(nodeURL), capability);

    TouchAction  touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);
    MultiTouchAction  multiTouchAction = new MultiTouchAction(driver);

    WebElement search = (WebElement)   driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().resourceId(\"com.google.android.apps.maps:id/search_omnibox_container\")"));
     touchAction .tap(search).perform();

        int leftX = search.getLocation().getX();
        int rightX = search.getSize().getWidth() + leftX;


        int upperY = search.getLocation().getY();
        int lowerY = search.getSize().getHeight() + upperY;

       a1 = touchAction.press(search,x1,y1).waitAction(2000).moveTo(search,x3,y1).release();
       a2 = touchAction.press(search,x2,y1).waitAction(2000).moveTo(search,x4,y1).release();

       multiTouchAction.add(a1).add(a2).perform();
```

Also, look [here](https://appium.readthedocs.io/en/stable/en/writing-running-appium/touch-actions/) for appium MultiTouch and [here](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/7486) for passing offset x,y co-ordinates to `moveTo`

Comment: The above code is not working for zoom the Mobile web browser using Appium.

I am getting the following error.
Method has not yet been implemented

Here is the code snippet

MultiTouchAction multiTouch = new MultiTouchAction(driver);
TouchAction action0 = new TouchAction(driver).tap(element);
multiTouch.add(action0).perform();

Actually we are trying to click a link in Mobile web browser using linktext but the text is very small so the click is not working properly. So we are trying to zoom the browser and click on it.

Comment: TouchAction and MultiTouchAction will only work for native view.