# ZoomIn/ZoomOut methods on Java in Appium

Tags: java, android, automation, appium, appium-android

could you please help me with zoom/pinch working methods on Java for Android in Appium?

I've already tried suggested implementation with MultiTouch action ([How to zoom in a mobile web using Appium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47137607/how-to-zoom-in-a-mobile-web-using-appium)) and this solution (https://appiumpro.com/editions/67). It's only I can see on emulator screen is slight twitching of the map.

There are no any errors in stack trace, seems like nothing occurs.

I use uiAutomator2 for Android 8 or 9. The only solution for ZoomIn I found is double click on some point in the screen. But for pinch action there are no known working ways so far.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is [Appium::MultiTouch.zoom](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/appium/ruby_lib/Appium%2FMultiTouch.zoom) function which basically places fingers onto screen edges and puts them together, you can use its implementation as the baseline for your test
2. There is [Pinch](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Pinch) function in [SeeTest - Appium Extension](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/SeeTest+-+Appium+Extension) which provides easy method to perform zoom in and out using simple API

Answer (score 0):

I use it for Android in Appium (edit: the element I try to pinch is big on the screen, so I add a little bit of extra so it doesn't touch the borders of the screen):

```
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("percent", 1.00);
    params.put("left",element.getLocation().getX()+50);
    params.put("top",element.getLocation().getY()-50);
    params.put("width",element.getRect().getHeight()-50);
    params.put("height",element.getRect().getWidth()-50);

    JavascriptExecutor js = driver;
    js.executeScript("mobile: pinchCloseGesture", params);
```

More info here: https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/android-mobile-gestures.md